# Trying to connect to mysql via php command line through XAMPP (ubuntu/cakephp)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, command-line-interface, cakephp

I am trying to run the cake shell through xampp and I am running into some issues.

**What works**

- I can connect PHP to Mysql while running through apache (in web
  browser)
- I can run the PHP CLI in bash by typing php, I set up the
  bin folder under xampp as an environment variable
- I can run cake, I
  set up the cake/console directory as an environment variable
- I can run my shell scripts for cake without any models attached

**What doesn't work**

Running shell scripts when models are attached. I get the following error: PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 561

**What I tried**

Originally, the cli was reporting that it couldn't find mysql_connect. So I installed php5-mysql despite my better judgement (I thought XAMPP would have already made the neccesary relationships). After I installed it, it was looking for mysql.sock. I tried changing the location under /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. Perhaps that is not the right location, or maybe I didn't change the correct variable.

**Questions**

Where can I change where the mysql.sock is located?
Or, I am doing this incorrectly, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You should find where a `my.cnf` file is located for your setup, I guess it's somewhere under `/opt/lampp/etc` or something like this. This file has a `[mysqld]` section with `socket=/path/to/mysql.sock` parameter. You can use `find /opt/lampp -name my.cnf` to find the config file.

Answer (score 1):

So... my shortcut solution was:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

It worked after that. I tried to copy /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf to /etc/mysql/my.cnf, but that didn't change the error.

I hope this helps someone :)!